# How can i receive mail faster using mail() function in PHP script?

Tags: php, email

```
<?php
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(-1);

$sender = '<test@musicschoolofdelhi.com>';
$recipient = 'anshukrpatel01@gmail.com';
$recipient2 = 'manu22425@gmail.com';

$subject = "Confirming this mail";
$message = "You are subscribed 9:28";
$message2 = "You have a new Subscriber 9:28";
$headers = 'From:' . $sender;
$s1 = mail($recipient, $subject, $message, $headers);
$s2 = mail($recipient2, $subject, $message2, $headers);
if($s1 && $s2)
{
    echo "Message accepted";
}
else
{
    echo "Error: Message not accepted";
}
?>
```

**I want to send two mails using mail() function from PHP script and it works fine but i am receiving mails after 2-3 hours which is too late. Please help me out so that I can receive mails fast. Moreover is it right for me to call mail() function twice to send two different mails to two different people at the same  time.**

Answer (score 0):

The delay probably has nothing to do with PHP itself, however
in your php.ini you can configure how your mail is handled by your server or provider.

This is most of the time 'sendmail' is the default. Anyway from php.ini  it's configured how it has been send. Followed up by the server configuration behind it

The delay can be caused by many reasons, for example blacklisting, missing SPF records, incorrect bounce address or return path, unresolveable hosts, missing mx records on your return path, and so on...

To debug this, you could send the mail to https://www.mail-tester.com/.
and check the results, and can see what might be holding up your email.
However it probably is not a 'code' issue.

Furthermore(but not relevant to your issue):
Sending 2 mails after each other, in a single try.. is not really failure proof. Mail is intended to fail, therefore people can specify many receiving mail servers (mx) so, if you build something where mail is important, you should do something on error handling and retrying... in cases where it's relevant. You could also look into using something like mailables from laravel, which also make them Queable, so this is non blocking for the request. Take a look at: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mail

If your script is a handling a webrequest instead of a CLI script, the end user might have to wait for 10 seconds or more, before it finished, depending on the speed and load on the mailserver, that is handling your mail() function.

Therefore queuing email is a recommendation.